# Unable to Access Extension Method in Main Method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using extension method to convert string to integer. But i am not able to access extension method in main method. What was i did wrong. My Code is below

```
public static class ConvertIntExtensionMethod
{
    public static int ConvertToInt(this int str) {
        int value;
        value = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        return value;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "100";
        //int i = 10;
        //bool result = i.IsGreaterThan(100);
        int result = str.ConvertIntExtensionMethod(); //Here is the problem
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

please try to help me thank you...

Comment: Why are you doing `str.ConvertIntExtensionMethod()`? Why not `ConvertIntExtensionMethod(srt)`?

Comment: it shows non-invocable member

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say `ConvertIntExtentionMethod.ConvertToInt(str)`. That sounds like what you want to do, but that would be inputting a string and not an int.

Comment: It's been some time, but I'll just add, the proper term for a "method" is a "function" in C#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am give the wrong parameter type in the extension method. Main method passing string value but extension method parameter is integer. This is the problem what i found.

Updated code in Extension method is given below

```
public static int ConvertToInt(this string str)
{
    int value;
    value = Convert.ToInt32(str);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` does not contain any member known as `ConvertIntExtensionMethod()`. You need to do this:

```
public static class ConvertIntExtensionMethod
{
    public static int ConvertToInt(this string str)
    {
        int value;
        value = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        return value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "5";
        //int i = 10;
        //bool result = i.IsGreaterThan(100);
        int result = ConvertIntExtensionMethod.ConvertToInt(str); //Here is the problem
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It will convert an integer as a `string` to an `int`.

Comment: @mjwills You are right. I mistyped - I was thinking about using `Convert.ToInt32()` without the extension method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class, it seems that your `ConvertIntExtensionMethod` class is a nested class
2. If you want to add this method to `string`, the type of the param must be `this string`
3. Call `str.ConvertToInt()` instead of `str.ConvertIntExtensionMethod()`